# Issue on ShephredJS tour step action

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

The following is example for a tour step

```
tour.addStep(0, {
title: 'Choosing Menu',
text: 'By clicking the arrow you can select the options.',
attachTo: '.my-list bottom',
classes: 'shepherd shepherd-open shepherd-theme-default ',
buttons: [{
    text: 'Next',
    action: tour.show(2),
    classes: 'shepherd-button-example-primary'
}]});
```

In the above code the action part doesn't works. But if put `tour.next` instead of `tour.show()`. The flow continues with "step 1".
The same `tour.show(2)` works at the browser console! if I directly put this line on the console.

Is there any possibilities to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Button action need to be a function. In your example `tour.next` is method of tour object. If you want do something with `show()` try this:

`action: function(){ return tour.show(2) }`